# how to test FCN(voc-fcn8s) on caffe python?

Tags: python, caffe, convolution

I want to test the FCN caffemodel given by [shelhamer](https://github.com/shelhamer/fcn.berkeleyvision.org) with the image:

[image]

But I not sure how to run the test program and show the labeled image.

the code I though about is as following:

```
import caffe
caffe_root = 'fcn.berkeleyvision.org-master/voc-fcn8s/'
model_def = caffe_root + 'deploy.prototxt'
model_weights = caffe_root + 'fcn8s-heavy-pascal.caffemodel'
test_image = caffe_root + 'test.jpg'

net = caffe.Net(model_def, model_weights, caffe.TEST)
image = caffe.io.load_image(test_image)
```

So what is the next can anyone help me? I am struggling in here for serial days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could refer to [`infer.py`](https://github.com/shelhamer/fcn.berkeleyvision.org/blob/master/infer.py) in the repository.

```
# load image, switch to BGR, subtract mean, and make dims C x H x W for Caffe
im = Image.open('pascal/VOC2010/JPEGImages/2007_000129.jpg')
in_ = np.array(im, dtype=np.float32)
in_ = in_[:,:,::-1]
in_ -= np.array((104.00698793,116.66876762,122.67891434))
in_ = in_.transpose((2,0,1))

# load net
net = caffe.Net('voc-fcn8s/deploy.prototxt', 'voc-fcn8s/fcn8s-heavy-pascal.caffemodel', caffe.TEST)
# shape for input (data blob is N x C x H x W), set data
net.blobs['data'].reshape(1, *in_.shape)
net.blobs['data'].data[...] = in_
# run net and take argmax for prediction
net.forward()
out = net.blobs['score'].data[0].argmax(axis=0)
```

It is vital to reshape the data layer since the shape of test images could be different.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://github.com/malreddysid/caffe_scripts/blob/master/eval_FCN.py) is a script I use to run inference on a batch of files. I think the command you are looking for is

```
net.forward()
```

To get the output image from the network, use the following commands.

```
out = net.blobs['score'].data # Extract the output
out = out.argmax(axis=1) # Get the labels at each pixel
out = out.transpose(1, 2, 0) # Reshape the output into an image
out = np.tile(out, (1,3))
```